# Xcode: How to call a method from a another view? Interaction between views

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitableview

I have a view controller with another view controller as a child controller, and
a table view controller also as a child controller. My first child is like a toolbar with several buttons, but without any methods.   What I need is, when a button from the first child is tapped, this view must call a method with the button's tag (all the buttons have
different tag) from the table view controller to filter the list. So, what I need to know control the interaction between these child controllers?

Thank you.

Comment: you can't have a viewcontroller as a subview in another viewcontroller . a view controller usually contains a main View and add other subviews to it .. you need to get your basic concepts sorted out.

Comment: Ok, i guess my explanation is wrong. I have a viewcontroller which has a viewcontroller with buttons as subview and a tableviewcontroller as subview too

Comment: you can comunicate between different viewControllers by using notification, delegation or kvo.. you choose

Comment: You can't have a `UIViewController` subviewed in a `UIViewController`. You either have two separate `UIViewControllers` or you have `UIViews` subviewed in a `UIViewController`. If you have two separate `UIViewControllers` just search on google for "Communicating between `UIViewControlller` there are thousands of questions to do with this.

Comment: What I'm doing is this... I have a NavigationController. In this NavigationController, I add a ViewController. In this ViewController, I'm adding the View's from another 2 ViewController. The first ViewController (upper) has several buttons, and the other ViewController (lower) is a TableViewController, but I'm just adding the views from this ViewControllers as subViews., using function "addSubview". What I need is when I tap one bottom from the upper subView, change the content from the lower subView, so... Who can I interact/communicate between this subViews?

Answer (score 0):

Handling changes, actions, or user interaction in other views is the essential use case of [delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).  The best practice is to have the first view controller be the delegates of the child view controllers, and then as events happen in the children, they calls certain methods on their delegates to notify it.  In response to the delegate calls you could then reload the table view, disable/enable buttons, or any other updates you need to do.

Other options for keeping values/state in sync between views are:

- [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) - best used for data
- [Key-Value Observation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) - best used for data
- `NSNotification`s sent through [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - best used for actions